# How to configure folder name case sensitivity in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, filenames

I need to create files named `abc.txt` and `ABC.txt`.  By default, Windows 7 will not allow this.  Somebody please help me to solve.

NB: nfsadmin is not working in my system.

Answer (score 2):

### Via GUI:

1. Open Services for Network File System: click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click  Services for Network File System (NFS).
2. If necessary, connect to the computer you want to manage.
3. Right-click Server for NFS, and then click Properties.
4. Click the Filename Handling tab.
5. Do one of the following:

   - **To enable case-sensitive file and directory name lookups:**
     Select the Enable case sensitive filename support in Server for NFS check box.
   - **To disable case-sensitive file and directory name lookups:**
     Clear the Enable case sensitive filename support in Server for NFS check box.

### Via the registry:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel
```

DWORD “*obcaseinsensitive*”

- 1 = system default - insensitive
- 0 = case sensitive

Source: [Configure Case Sensitivity for File and Folder Names](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725747.aspx)

Comment: **Note:** Both need to be done as informed by the link, it's best to do a reboot too...

Comment: Applies To: Windows Server 2008 R2